# HTML attribute "target" in links: browsing context

Tags: html, target

There seems to be an odd behavior when using the target attribute in a link, e.g.:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.sydneyoperahouse.com/" target="sehenswuerdigkeit">Opernhaus</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.powerhousemuseum.com/" target="sehenswuerdigkeit">Powerhouse Museum science+design</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/" target="sehenswuerdigkeit">Botanic Gardens</a></li>
</ul>
```

The last link causes that whatever link is clicked afterwards a *new* browser window is being opened. The expected behavior is to open the link in the browsing context "sehenswuerdigkeit" (= "place of interest"). All other links work fine. It seems like opening this site destroys the browsing context.

I've tried it using Chrome 17, Safari 5.0.1 and Firefox; working on Mac OS 10.5.

Comment: what is this target targetting at? iframe? frame? new window? what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's actually the second link sir...it is corrupting the target with javascript.

http://www.powerhousemuseum.com/

Comment: Oh boy - I am sorry: You are right, it is the second link. My apologies for this mistake. What kind of corruption with JavaScript is going on?

Comment: you know, there is so much scripts going on with that site that it's really hard to figure it out. I'm not even sure exactly what method it's using...you might want to look into this link below, or maybe a frame within a frame...or, stop trying to control the destination and just let them open in new windows every time...loading sites in a frame and trying to control it is not that great of an idea...look for another solution...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller

Answer (score 0):

target in this sense is not a location, it is for the browser to tell what it needs to do.

Try making target="_self", and putting that property value of sehenswuerdigkeit in another property.\

Also, what is the expected behavior, 'sehenswuerdigkeit' is not a target, and I'm not sure what you mean by 'browsing context' in your request.